# SQL Server 2005: Row in backup, missing in database

Tags: sql-server, restore, database-backup

I've got a MS-SQL 2005 backup file. When I open with a text editor, despite being binary, I can see some information I want back.

Nevertheless, when I restore the backup using MS-SQL studio, the row is missing in the table.

Is there some way I could get that piece of information back which is inside the backup file but missing when I restore it? (Maybe it was logical deleted, or something like that)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
insert into livedb.schema.table select * from restoredb.schema.table where rowid = 5
```

or whatever criteria uniquely identifies your row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I did so far: `restore database restoredb from disk ... with ... recovery`. Then, `select * from restoredb.myschema.mytable where myfield = XXX`, but it does not get the row I'm looking for. What am I missing?

Comment: Either that row was already deleted by the time the backup happened or your select from the restored database isn't doing what you think it is.  If it's feasible, "eyeball" the table (that is, select from it with no where clause and look for the data that you expect).

Comment: Yes, the row was probably deleted from the table by the time we made the backup. But if I open the .bak file using Notepad++ and make a search, I can still find the information inside. So I would like to know if there is some MSSQL "trick" to recover this old data still in backup file.